# Intent is not fulfilling after Confirmation propmt

Tags: amazon-lex

I am working on lexing and want to fulfill the intent when all slot values are filled. But the intent is not fulfilling after the confirmation prompt. it is asking, again and again, a Confirmation prompt but not fulfilling the intent. I have code in python So please check if there is anything wrong in my code. Thanks.

see screenshot.

[image]

[image]

I am also attaching the code please check.

```js
import json
def flightDecision(currName, currSlots, Departure_city, Arrival_city, ReturnDate, Departing, Date, Flight_schedule):
    if Departing == "roundtrip" and Date == None:
        return{
            "dialogAction": {
                "type": "ElicitSlot",
                "slotToElicit": "Date",
                "intentName": 'Bookaflight',
                "slots": {
                  "Departure_city": Departure_city,
                  "Arrival_city": Arrival_city,
                  "Departing": Departing,
                  "Date": Date,
                },
            },
        }
    if Departing == 'roundtrip' and Date != None and ReturnDate == None:
        return{
            "dialogAction": {
                "type": "ElicitSlot",
                "slotToElicit": "ReturnDate",
                "intentName": 'Bookaflight',
                "slots": {
                  "Departure_city": Departure_city,
                  "Arrival_city": Arrival_city,
                  "Departing": Departing,
                  "Date": Date,
                  "ReturnDate": ReturnDate,
                },
            },
        }
    if Departing == 'roundtrip' and ReturnDate != None and Flight_schedule == None:
         return{
            "dialogAction": {
                "type": "ElicitSlot",
                "slotToElicit": "Flight_schedule",
                "intentName": 'Bookaflight',
                "slots": {
                  "Departure_city": Departure_city,
                  "Arrival_city": Arrival_city,
                  "Departing": Departing,
                  "Date": Date,
                  "ReturnDate": ReturnDate,
                  "Flight_schedule": Flight_schedule
                },
            },
        }
    if Departing == "oneway" and Date == None:
        return{
            "dialogAction": {
                "type": "ElicitSlot",
                "slotToElicit": "Date",
                "intentName": 'Bookaflight',
                "slots": {
                  "Departure_city": Departure_city,
                  "Arrival_city": Arrival_city,
                  "Departing": Departing,
                  "Date": Date,
                },
            },
        }
    if Departing == 'oneway' and Date != None and Flight_schedule == None:
        return{
            "dialogAction": {
                "type": "ElicitSlot",
                "slotToElicit": "Flight_schedule",
                "intentName": 'Bookaflight',
                "slots": {
                  "Departure_city": Departure_city,
                  "Arrival_city": Arrival_city,
                  "Departing": Departing,
                  "Date": Date,
                  "Flight_schedule": Flight_schedule,
                },
            },
        }
        
    return{
        "dialogAction":{
            "type": "ConfirmIntent",
            "intentName": "Bookaflight",
            "slots":{
                "Departure_city": Departure_city,
                 "Arrival_city": Arrival_city,
                 "Departing": Departing,
                 "Date": Date,
                 "ReturnDate": ReturnDate,
                 "Flight_schedule": Flight_schedule,
                #  "message":{
                #      "contentType": "PlainText",
                #      "message": "you want to book a ticket"
                #  }
            }
        }
    }
    
def delegate(currSlots, currName, Departure_city, Arrival_city, Departing, Date, Flight_schedule):
    return{
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Delegate',
            'slots': currSlots
        }
    }
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    currName = event['currentIntent']['name']
    currSlots = event['currentIntent']['slots']
    Departing = event['currentIntent']['slots']['Departing']
    ReturnDate = event['currentIntent']['slots']['ReturnDate']
    Arrival_city = event['currentIntent']['slots']['Arrival_city']
    Departure_city = event['currentIntent']['slots']['Departure_city']
    Date = event['currentIntent']['slots']['Date']
    Flight_schedule = event['currentIntent']['slots']['Flight_schedule']
    
    while not Departing:
        return delegate(currSlots, currName, Departure_city, Arrival_city,Departing,Date, Flight_schedule)
    else:
        return flightDecision(currSlots, currName, Departure_city, Arrival_city, ReturnDate, Departing, Date, Flight_schedule)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same Lambda function for both validation and fulfillment, you would need to check the `invocationSource` and decide how to proceed accordingly. Since intent confirmation is also enabled, also use the `confirmationStatus` parameter to know whether the user confirmed or denied the prompt.

Check the input event format for the JSON structure passed by Lex to the codehook Lambda: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-input-event-format

Comment: I didn't attach any lambda function in fulfillment. On fulfillment, i only want to return the parameter to the client. but I am unable to do that I dont't want to do any other activity on fulfillment just want to return parameter to client if user enter yes on confirmation prompt